# Best Maple locations after a dungeon in Oracle of Ages?

Tags: zelda-oracle-of-ages

## Background

Maple appears after defeating a certain amount of enemies ([30 or more](https://zelda.fandom.com/wiki/Maple#The_Legend_of_Zelda:_Oracle_of_Ages_and_Oracle_of_Seasons) without [Maple's Ring](https://zelda.fandom.com/wiki/Maple%27s_Ring)), and dungeons contain a lot of enemies.

As soon as you leave a dungeon, you're bound to encounter maple.

## Problem

Some areas are filled with water or have holes, causing many items to fall in, becoming unobtainable.

Some areas large amounts of clipped areas, not allowing you to pick up most items, due to them being out of reach.

## Question

With gale seeds unlocked, which areas should a player teleport to (or walk to) after a dungeon, with intentions to encounter Maple, ensuring the lowest change of items dropped by Maple into an out-of-reach area?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this map online, it shows the locations where you can find Maple in the past:

[image: A world map of the past in Oracle of Ages, I found it here: https://faqs.neoseeker.com/Games/GBC/zelda_oracle_of_ages_maple_past.gif]

3 of the locations on the talus peak are surprisingly open, they are hard to reach though, especially if you don't want to trigger an encounter with Maple on the way there. They are potentially the best places though. **These are the best locations to encounter her in the past**

[image: A part of the map, with 3 marks indicating the screens where it's good to encounter maple]

The screen east of the Lynna Village Shooting Gallery is very open if you remove all 20 cuttable bushes.

This is the map for the present with all locations where Maple can spawn:

[image: A world map of the present in Oracle of Ages, I found it here: https://faqs.neoseeker.com/Games/GBC/zelda_oracle_of_ages_maple_present.gif]

There are three good spots in the Forrest of Time, though the north east one is the best. The south one has some cuttable bushes. **The north one is the best place to encounter Maple, because it is somewhat accessible and very open**

[image: How to get to the best location without triggering Maple on the way there]

There is a good place on the Talus peak in the present, too, it is located at the same place as the most south one from the past (from the three good ones).

Both Maple locations on the Yoll Graveyard are good and open, the north one has 4 cuttable bushes.

There is one potentially good location is the south east screen of the Rolling Ridge Base (The same screen where she can appear in the past), it is impossible to reach without triggering Maple on your way there, unless you didn't yet fill the kill counter. It may be possible to do it with very targeted time manipulation, but it feels like doing so actually resets the counter (someone please confirm this).

Comment: My problem with the highlighted suggested location (Forest of Time) is the risk of meeting Maple before reaching the destination. It may be a good area, but it's not concrete, unless there's a way to control Maple's appearance, ensuring she won't be met on the way to the destination. Not to say it wouldn't be good for farming Maple (switching between 2 screens, fighting enemies, til an encounter), which is why I upvoted. But it's just too risky to be considered the best.

Comment: @VinceEmigh I added in a route to get there. If you take a wrong turn, then both other locations that you may end up with instead are somewhat good as well.

Comment: @VinceEmigh I played this game several years ago and used that save file to go there. I vaguely remember the path to the Maku tree being blocked for most of the game. Does that apply to the present? If the path to the Maku tree isn't blocked, then you can get to the suggested location while ensuring that you won't meet her on the way. Otherwise I will change it, due to inaccessibility.